# Run python file -- what function is main?

Tags: python

I have simple python script, 'first.py':

```
#first.py
def firstFunctionEver() :
    print "hello"

firstFunctionEver()
```

I want to call this script using : `python first.py` and have it call the `firstFunctionEver()`. But, the script is ugly -- what function can I put the call to `firstFunctionEver()` in and have it run when the script is loaded?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    firstFunctionEver()
```

Read more at the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 10):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    firstFunctionEver()
```

Comment: What is `__name__` and when is it `__main__`? Please explain and provide references.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you explicitly said you want to call your script using `python first.py`. However you could consider calling your script in different way without even changing any code.

Let's say your project structure is of the form `first_pckg/first.py`. You can rename your `first.py` to `__main__.py`. Also include a `__init__.py` empty file to mark the directory as a python package. You can then simply call your package like this:

```
$ python -m first_pckg
hello
```